# Django Template Check user is authenticated and is present

Tags: django, authentication, django-templates, django-views

I am creating a user login and changing the link of **signin** to **signout** .

The views.py i have is:

```
#This index is for my landing page i.e.first.html where I have Sigin link which needs to hidden on Successful
def index(request):
    if 'username' not in request.session :
        return render_to_response('gharnivas/ghar.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
    u = request.session['username']
    return render_to_response('gharnivas/ghar.html',{ 'user' : u },context_instance=RequestContext(request))


#This here, is the view for my check the user and create required
def ulogin(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404('Only POSTs are allowed')
    try:
        m = Personal.objects.get(name__icontains=request.POST['username'])
        if m.password == request.POST['password']:
            request.session['username'] = m.id
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    except Personal.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response('gharnivas/signin.html', {'error' : True }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The urls.py is :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'gharnivas.views.index'),#landing page
    url(r'^signin/$','gharnivas.views.signin'),#The view for sign In page
    url(r'^ulogin/$','gharnivas.views.ulogin'),#The view for creating a change in user login
}
```

Then in the Landing page i.e. first.html I have this code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    {% if user %}
            <div class="whitecolor"  >
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">SignOut</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    {% else %}
            <a href="/signin/">SignIn</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    {% endif %}
        </td>       
    <td><a href="/register/">Register</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="/"> Home </a></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

But on the url entered, I dont get to see Sigin Link , but I get Signout.
When i change `{% if user %}` to `{% if not user %}` then Signin is seen.

Please let me know where i am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is no more, after i cleared the browser history and also added `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True`
in settings.py. Restarted the Django server after syncdb.
Worked

Answer (score 2):

`user` is always true. You must call the [`is_authenticated()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) method.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

Comment: @Ignacio Now I do get SignIn link shown. But it doesn't get change to Signout when actually the user is signed in. :(

Comment: And i am not going for the default Login of django. I am choosing custom, wherein i am going ahead with sessions to keep track

Comment: What for? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Comment: I wanted to try with sessions which are custom. But the doubt is still there, because how can that `if` statement not work? I even changed the `user` to just another variable `cu` or so. !! :|

Comment: If you're using a completely custom auth method then you have to use whatever that auth method uses to indicate whether or not the user is authenticated.

Comment: @Ignacio, I understand what you mean. But the doubt is with change in variable name also it is not working :( . Now, its pricking me only about that if loop not working properly. Not about the authentication.